# Extract a specific number from a string using pattern in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have

```
test<-"owidhsf 2121 .Record: 1111, Field: kjhdlksd 22 33 455"
```

I would like to extract `1111`

I cannot use `substr()` because the length of the string is variable. But the required output (`1111`) will always be within the pattern `Record: 1111, Field`

Tidyverse solution prefered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest `stringr` (1.5.0), you can extract the capturing group with `str_extract` -

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(test, 'Record:\\s+(\\d+)', group = 1)
#[1] "1111"
```

This internally, calls `str_match` i.e

```
str_match(test, 'Record:\\s+(\\d+)')[, 2]
#[1] "1111"
```

Answer (score 3):

If the digits succeeds the `Record:` , then use `str_extract` with a regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(test, "(?<=Record: )\\d+")
[1] "1111"
```

---

Or in `base R`, we can capture the digits

```
sub(".*\\s\\.Record:\\s+(\\d+),\\s*Field.*", "\\1", test)
[1] "1111"
```